# jQuery UI sortable placeholder with Bootstrap rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a draggable set of panels using jQuery UI and Bootstrap rows/panels. I've got something which mostly works, my problem is that the placeholder isn't sized correctly when you drag the panel. It's the size of the entire row instead of the size of the element.

```js
$('.row').sortable({
 connectWith: ".panel",
 handle: ".panel-heading",
 placeholder: "panel-placeholder"
});

$('.panel').on('mousedown', function(){
 $(this).css( 'cursor', 'move' );
}).on('mouseup', function(){
 $(this).css( 'cursor', 'auto' );
});;
```

```css
.panel-placeholder {
 border: 1px dotted black;
 margin: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
 height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     Panel content
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     Panel content
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     Panel content
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.col-md-4').sortable({
    connectWith: ".col-md-4",
    handle: ".panel-heading",
    placeholder: "panel-placeholder"
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zdfb3e0p/8/

Any ideas?

Comment: I edited the CSS in your fiddle, changing your `.panel-placeholder`'s `margin` property to `margin: 1em 1em 1em 1em;` seems to work well enough for me. Or you can use `margin: 15px 1em 1em 15px;` which is more in line with the margins and paddings of bootstrap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpherV solution works. Here's however a simplified version that still works and tries to keep *separation of concerns* by leaving CSS matters on the CSS code.
I've tried to keep padding/margin interactions on the js code itself minimum.

The idea is the same, I get the `width` and `height` directly from the `.panel`, and I copy *as is* all the classes on the `col-` div. But margins and paddings are set via CSS to match Bootstrap's Default.

You can find it on the snippet below, or here on the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/zdfb3e0p/16/

```js
$('.row').sortable({
     connectWith: ".panel",
     handle: ".panel-heading",
     placeholder: "panel-placeholder",
     start: function(e, ui){
         ui.placeholder.width(ui.item.find('.panel').width());
         ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.find('.panel').height());
         ui.placeholder.addClass(ui.item.attr("class"));
     }
});

$('.panel').on('mousedown', function(){
  $(this).css( 'cursor', 'move' );
}).on('mouseup', function(){
  $(this).css( 'cursor', 'auto' );
});;
```

```css
.panel-placeholder {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 15px 20px 15px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     Panel content
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     Panel content
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     Panel content
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Elegant! The only caveat is if your element has classes other than the Bootstrap ones but I guess you can filter those out

Comment: Yeah, to be fair I consider your solution way more "bullet-proof", specially on the class management. But since OP asked for simplified solution I thought I could contribute with my grain of sand.

Comment: I awarded OpherV the points as he was the first to come up with a working solution. I awarded you the accepted answer as it's the solution I ended up using.

Answer (score 16):

If you wish your placeholder to have the item's exact dimensions, you can use the Sortable `start` event, [as described in the API](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start), to compute and affect the same styling as dragging starts.

Once you have the reference of both the placeholder element, as well as the handle element from the event, you can just copy each relevant CSS attribute.

In addition, in order to maintain the positioning in the grid as the original element, you will have to make sure to assign the proper `col` class from the original element. I also accounted for some quirks, like the fact that by default the jQuery placeholder is assigned an inline margin, and that the dashed border also takes up some space.

```
$('.row').sortable({
    connectWith: ".panel",
    handle: ".panel-heading",
    placeholder: "panel-placeholder",
    start: function(event, ui){
        var classes = ui.item.attr('class').split(/\s+/);
        for(var x=0; x<classes.length;x++){   
            if (classes[x].indexOf("col")>-1){
            ui.placeholder.addClass(classes[x]);
           }
         }

        ui.placeholder.css({      
          width: ui.item.innerWidth() - 30 + 1, //account for margin and border
          height: ui.item.innerHeight() - 15 + 1, //account for margin and border    
          padding: ui.item.css("padding"), //use original padding
          marginTop: 0 //dispose of the jQuery margin
        });       

    }
  }
});
```

Here's a [working fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/49vpya6y/6/)

I made sure to test this in all responsive modes

[image]

Comment: You are almost there. You need to put the code in the fiddle and solve the margins of the placeholder.

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't thought of that when I was doing my original design. The minimum time limit for awarding a bounty is 24 hours, but provided there are no simpler solutions I'll award the bounty to you then.

Comment: How'd you make that neato gif?

Comment: @adamdport A software called LICEcap :)

Comment: I awarded the bounty to you since you were the first one to come up with a solution. I awarded the solution to Juan as that's the solution I ended up using.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap's Grid system has a default `30px` padding (15px per side).  Since you are tying the sort to `.row` you need to account for that.  Changing your `margin` value on `.panel-placeholder` to `15px` will cause it to fall in line with Bootstrap's Grid Framework.

```js
$('.row').sortable({
 connectWith: ".panel",
 handle: ".panel-heading",
 placeholder: "panel-placeholder"
});

$('.panel').on('mousedown', function(){
 $(this).css( 'cursor', 'move' );
}).on('mouseup', function(){
 $(this).css( 'cursor', 'auto' );
});;
```

```css
.panel-placeholder {
 border: 1px dotted black;
 margin: 15px;
 height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     Panel content
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     Panel content
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     Panel content
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lhmujrzz/